# Convert DIB to DDB?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, gdi+, clipboard, gdi

I'm developing a clipboard manager (which can be seen here: http://flamefusion.net/software/shapeshifter).

However, I am currently having issues with a bitmap (`bmp`) that won't really insert itself into the clipboard properly. My first approach was the following, using `SetClipboardData`.

```
var hBitmap = bmp.GetHBitmap();
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
```

I am aware of the potential memory leaks in this, and it was made solely as a test. The test failed. The image put into the clipboard was not readable by Paint when pasting it in.

So after a lot of researching and failed attempts, I got a new theory. The bitmap I am using is created from a `MemoryStream`, which has been created through a previous call to the `Bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageFormat)` method. This leads me to believe that a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`'s `GetHBitmap` is not the kind of `HBITMAP` the `SetClipboardData` function expects.

So I tried the following, with some kind of success.

```
var memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero);
var memBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(memDC, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, memBitmap);
```

Now the image is inserted with the right dimensions, but as a black image. And this is quite obvious, since nothing from `bmp` is actually used to create the "compatible" bitmap other than its width and height.

I assume I have to use BitBlt somehow to copy my original bitmap over to this now "compatible" bitmap, but I have no clue of where to begin.

Would any of you GDI wizards know? Magic is obviously needed here.

**Edit 1**
As dthorpe nicely pointed out, it seems that my problem is that the image I am trying to save is in fact a DIB. Now the question has changed. I need to figure out how to convert from a DIB to a DDB. I am aware of the alpha loss while doing this among other things, but it is nevertheless needed.

**Edit 2**
It is not acceptable to use `Clipboard.SetImage`. This won't work in my scenario. I need to use the APIs.

Comment: GetHBitmap() should work fine with the clipboard. Are you sure the original bitmap is valid? Can you display the original bitmap (created from a memory stream) on screen?

Comment: You don't want to convert to a DDB. You want to to `Bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageFormat.Bmp)` and then put that into the clipboard with `CF_DIB`.

Comment: That can't display in Paint. Can you answer with your code that actually demonstrates that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CF_BITMAP is probably the wrong format to use with your bitmap. The CF_BITMAP clipboard format specifies a device bitmap, but nearly all bitmaps today are DIBs - device independent bitmaps.  Device bitmaps are relative to the system/hardware device palette (think EGA graphics) and must match the pixel format of the current display mode. DIBs carry their own color info and their pixel format is independent of the display mode.

Docs say that the clipboard manager will convert a CF_BITMAP to a CF_DIB if an application asks for CF_DIB when reading from the clipboard, but that assumes that the original image is actually a device bitmap in the current display mode pixel format. If it is not, the conversion will produce garbage because the input is garbage.

Try again using CF_DIB instead of CF_BITMAP.

Comment: I am aware of this, but it must be CF_BITMAP. I already handle DIB and I'm also well aware that they can be auto converted. I still need it to work with CF_BITMAP.

Comment: What are you doing to ensure that the bitmap handle returned by bitmap.GetHBitmap() is a device bitmap? I'm pretty sure the .net Bitmap class constructs DIBs by default.

Comment: Aha, so GetHBitmap can be both? I didn't know. How can I convert if needed, and how do I check if it is indeed a device bitmap?

Comment: A Win32 HBitmap can refer to a DIB or DDB, yes. I don't know if the .NET bitmap class can be forced to produce a DDB, though.

Comment: See the last paragraph here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183561(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It's been 20 years since I last worked with Windows DDBs.  I'm a little rusty. ;>

Comment: `CF_DIB` and `Bitmap.Save` will work out fine, but it's way too complex.

Comment: @dthorpe I can't get the instructions from that documentation working. Can you show me in code with a new answer? I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: CreateCompatibleDC, CreateCompatibleBitmap, select that bitmap into that DC, then bitblt from your DIB into that DC.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are over-complicating this. There's really no need for p/invoke at all – the framework already handles this for you. You can do this as a one-liner:

```
Clipboard.SetImage(bmp);
```

Comment: I need to use PInvoke because the clipboard in .NET is very buggy, as many other posts have already detailed.

Comment: Well, I find that somewhat hard to believe.

Comment: So did I. It doesn't take much Googling to figure out all the hacks people have needed to get around things.

Comment: I'm curious, could you point me to some of these bugs. I've never encountered problems. I wonder why not.

Comment: [source 1](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/726654/clipboard-has-different-undocumented-behavior-in-net-3-5-and-4) [source 2](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/687744/outofmemoryexception-when-pasting-from-clipboard) [source 3](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651891/fatalexecutionengineerror-on-clipboard-getdata-enhancedmetafile). The last one is the worst one - it can't be caught since it's a FatalException. There's no way out.

Comment: I didn't know this and wouldn't know either, if it wouldn't have been because I tried first. Shapeshifter 2 used .NET's inbuilt functions. It had crashes that couldn't be fixed. Yes, it's that bad. And no, it's still not fixed. Very disappointing when you look at .NET quality standards.

Comment: So yeah. Copy an image from Word, and GetData crashes because the clipboard will contain an enhanced metafile, without even checking the format type. There is no way to get around it.

Comment: Except that it is a hack. What if a guy has both an image and some text copied at the same time?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen - actually, I can't reproduce your Copy From Word -> GetData issue either (running VS2010/CLR4). OutOfMemory Exception during clipboard ops *may* happen (.NET or not).